# unordered_map and pointers with value semantics

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I've defined a type Term which is accessed by pointer but has value semantics; two different Term objects are logically equal if they have the same contents. I need to use them as map keys.

A first attempt might be `unordered_map<Term*, int>`, but this by itself doesn't get the value semantics. Needs custom hash and equality comparison functions. (For a number of reasons, I want to define these globally instead of having to supply them as extra template arguments in every case.)

The custom hash function can iirc be defined like

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<Term*> ...
```

But `unordered_map` compares keys with `==`, you can't define custom operators on built-in types, and all pointers are built-in types.

I could define a wrapper class that just holds a `Term*` and use that as the key. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: The simpler solution is to use the template arguments, surely? Can you explain why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @AlanStokes I'm going to be using such maps in a lot of places in the program. Having to supply the extra template arguments every time wouldn't be so bad if the result of forgetting to do so in a single case was a compile time error. However, setting up a situation where forgetting something means the program silently gives a wrong answer at runtime is a foreseeably bad idea.

Comment: A `typedef` (or alias declaration in these modern times) sounds like a simple solution to that. I don't really understand why you wouldn't have that anyway.

Comment: @AlanStokes True, maybe that's the answer, just define an alias and write a comment next to the class definition telling people to always use that alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `unordered_map`:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

you can see that you can define a custom operator for comparison as fourth template argument. In your case you would only supply them once at `unordered_map` creation without "having to supply them as extra template arguments in every case":

```
struct custom_operator {
    bool operator()(Term* lhs, Term* rhs) const { ... }
};
```

and then use it as:

```
std::unordered_map< Term*, int
                  , std::hash<Term*>
                  , custom_operator> map;
```

In any case I highly recommend not using a pointer as a key to the hash map. If logically you want `Term` to be the key, you should just have `std::unordered_map<Term, int>`.

Comment: Right, to clarify, by 'every case' I mean every time such a map is defined - that's going to be in a lot of places, and I'm wary about setting up a situation where forgetting an argument means the program start silently giving wrong answers. But I think I'm going to end up agreeing with your last paragraph: better to just make it a value class that holds pointers to variable-length data.

Comment: @rwallace put a typedef/alias somewhere. E.g. `template<typename To> using term_map = unordered_map<Term*, To, term_hash, term_equal>;`

Comment: @melak47 Yeah, and a comment by the class definition telling people to always use the alias. Maybe that's the way to go.